# Thesaurus for statistics and machine learning terms

Tags: machine-learning, terminology

Does there exist any reference thesaurus for statistics and machine learning terms? I know that Wikipedia articles often contain synonyms, but I would like to have a mere thesaurus  that I could go through easily (vs. a full encyclopedia) to make sure I know all the jargon.

Comment: What a great question! I would like this thesaurus, too. On the other hand, I think that there are often subtle nuances that may lay down some pitfalls. For example, I have herd the terms *hierarchical linear models*, *multilevel models*, *mixed models*, and *random effects models* (and possibly a few others) used as synonyms in ways that I understood, but I also can draw subtle (and perhaps not so subtly) distinctions between each of these terms.

Comment: Maybe you saw this: http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/stat315a/glossary.pdf? Far from comprehensive though

Comment: @AlexeyGrigorev lol "large grant = 1,000,000 USD (ML) == large grant = 50,000 USD (stats)"

Answer (score 4):

In this [link](http://www.john-ros.com/translator/) you can find my contribution to the matter.

It is work in progress so any comments will be appreciated.